# Reading Parquet files in s3 with Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

The goal is to merge multiple parquet files into a single Athena table so that I can query them.

I converted two parquet files from csv:

```
pandas.read_csv('a.csv').to_parquet('a.parquet', index=False)
pandas.read_csv('b.csv').to_parquet('b.parquet', index=False)
```

The CSV has the format `id,name,age`, for example:

```
1,john,20
2,mark,25
```

I upload these to the S3 bucket: `s3://my-test-bucket`, which is arranged as:

```
my-test-bucket
  -> folder1
    -> a.parquet
  -> folder2
    -> b.parquet
```

Then created the table in Athena via:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_table`(
  `id` int, 
  `name` string, 
  `age` int
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://my-test-bucket'
tblproperties ("parquet.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

However, when i try to query the table via:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

I get empty rows as my return. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with your parquet file. The way you do things after the parquet file creation (creating the table, etc) looks correct. I honestly never tried using a parquet file directly generated from pandas (I think it caused me troubles in the past). Instead, once I had the pandas DF I just converted it into a pyarrow DF and then write it into parquet. This worked for me in case you want to try.

Comment: @Roberto I did try converting into a pyarrow DF and then to parquet. But the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround is by using [AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler):

```
import awswrangler as wr

path = 's3://my-test-bucket'

# Assume the data has been extracted in dict form from .csv
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2],
    "name": ["John", "Jane"],
    "age": [10, 11],
    "folder": [1, 2]
})

wr.s3.to_parquet(
    df=df,
    path=path,
    dataset=True,
    mode="overwrite",
    partition_cols=["folder"]
)
```

This will generate in s3:

```
my-test-bucket
  -> folder=1
    -> <some hash>.parquet
  -> folder=2
    -> <some hash>.parquet
```